# c# app cannot run, CLR20r3, System.Data.SqlClient.Sql

Tags: c#, console-application, vmware-player

I am working on a c# console app & it works well on my computer. Trying to move it to VMware player which running windows 7. But when I try to start the exe file, it stopped working. The problem details are

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3   Problem Signature
>   01:   servercrawlerconsole.exe   Problem Signature 02:    1.0.0.0   Problem
>   Signature 03: 52942dc5   Problem Signature 04:    System.Data   Problem
>   Signature 05: 4.0.0.0   Problem Signature 06: 4ba1e064   Problem
>   Signature 07: 2795   Problem Signature 08:    29   Problem Signature
>   09:   System.Data.SqlClient.Sql   OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
>   Locale ID:    3081   Additional Information 1:    0a9e   Additional
>   Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional
>   Information 3:    0a9e   Additional Information
>   4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

I have no idea what it means. Please help for this;

Comment: There should be a log record in "Application" log with the stack trace of exception. Post it here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newer. Where can i find the log record.....

Comment: Win+R -> eventvwr -> Windows Logs -> Application (captions may differ, depending on your language settings).

Comment: @user2763566, u fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to database as part of your application start, than check that the user in the connection string is authorized to access your database.